# Centrar texto del campo

Tags: php, bootstrap

Soy algo nueva en php y bootstrap. me podrían ayudar estoy muy confundida trate de todas las formas pero no puedo solucionar:

- Como hago para que el campo de comprobación se ponga al frente de aceptación de términos y condiciones de uso
- Como puedo centrar la palabra únete de mi botón?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <div class="col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-12">
      <div class="checkbox">
        <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="accept" required> Acepto terminos y condiciones de uso
        </label>
      </div>                        
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class="container-xl">
                        <div class="wrap-login100-form-btn">
                                <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
                            <div class="text-center"> 
                             <button class="login100-form-btn" >       Sign Up       </button>
                            </div>  
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: El segundo punto es claro y simple de responder, pero el primero no entiendo que quieres lograr

Comment: Centrar la palabra UNETE en mi botón, si puedes visualizar la palabra UNETE esta hacia la izquierda y yo trato de que este en el centro pero no lo logro.

Comment: Ese punto si me queda claro, lo que no entiendo es lo que pides antes que eso

Comment: El pequeño cuadrito que esta encima de ACEPTACION DE TERMINOS Y CONDICIONES DE USO deseo que este al frente de ACEPTACION DE TERMINOS Y CONDICIONES DE USO (Imaginese que este * es el cuadrito ) * ACEPTACION DE TERMINOS Y CONDICIONES DE USO